# Jquery mvc file upload not targetting url when added Image file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5.2

please Help me How can i upload file using Jquery
When i use   `data: SubmitedData`  its working(Without Image File)
When i use Image file its not Targeting my url
This is my Html code

```
<form method="post" name="Form1">
    <input type="text"  id="EmployeeName" /><br />
    <input type="file" id="ImageFile" />  
    <input type="submit" value="Ok" id="BtnSubmit" />
</form>
```

Here i wrote simple Jq Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#BtnSubmit').click(function () {
            var fileUpload = $('#ImageFile').get(0)
            var files = fileUpload.files
            var length = files.length;
            var SubmitedData = {
                EmpId: $('#EmpId').val(),
                EmployeeName: $('#EmployeeName').val(),
                Emp_File: fileUpload                

            }
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3013/Dummy/FileRes',
                method: 'POST',
                data: SubmitedData   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must change your SubmitedData declaration to:

```
var SubmitedData = {
    EmpId: $('#EmpId').val(),
    EmployeeName: $('#EmployeeName').val(),
    Emp_File: files[0] 
}
```

In addition, you should change your button "BtnSubmit" to type="button" instead of "submit" (or control it with event event.preventDefault() inside your function) in order to avoid the form submits itself.

Comment: when i mentioned     Emp_File: files[0] 
 ajax is not working